# jQuery + CSS scroll to container part

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I have container with content bigger than this container.
I control it with jQuery and CSS. Buttons work ok, I click button#3 and it scrolls to third div's part.

(Demo: [click to show](http://shoutkey.com/sorta))

What I want to do is add controls to go to next / previous div part.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var slidePosition = 0;
$('#slide1_controls').on('click', 'div', function(){
$("#slide1_divs").css("transform","translateX("+$(this).index() * -900+"px)");
$("#slide1_controls div").removeClass("selected");
$(this).addClass("selected");
slidePosition = $(this).index();
});
$('#nastepny').on('click', function(){
$("#slide1_divs").css("transform","translateX("+ slidePosition * -900+"px)");
$("#slide1_controls div").removeClass("selected");
});
});
```

Line

```
$("#slide1_divs").css("transform","translateX("+$(this).index() * -900+"px)");
```

works fine.

This part

```
$("#slide1_divs").css("transform","translateX("+ slidePosition * -900+"px)");
```

doesn't.

I tried different variations, $(slidePosition), +($(slidePosition)) and many, many others.

Number instead of slidePosition variable works fine. alert(slidePosition) gives correct value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try : `slidePosition = +($(this).index()); // force return numeric` and `$("#slide1_divs").css("transform","translateX("+(-900*slidePosition)+"px)");`

Comment: i prepare a new solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this => [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dbTXh/1/)

```
$('#nastepny').on('click', function(){

    if(slidePosition<(slideCount-1)){
        slidePosition++;
        pos = +(slidePosition * -900);
       $("#slide1_divs").css("transform"," translateX("+pos+"px)");
       $("#slide1_controls div").removeClass("selected");  
    }else{
       // other action...
    }

});
```